# DATEADD issue within EXEC

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an `EXEC` statement that contains `DATEADD` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE curDate >= DATEADD(WEEK, 0, 2021-04-30) 
  AND curDate  < DATEADD(WEEK, 6500, 2021-04-30)
```

This statement works outside of the exec('') function, but will return no records if the second `DATEADD` has a value < 6000 while within the exec statement. 6000 weeks ahead is much larger than the target range, but this value determines if records are returned (all records for every date range) or if none are.

Is this a known issue with the exec statement?

Comment: Did you by any chance forget to add quotes to your date literals? `2021-04-30` is a calculation that yields an integer, not a date (unfortunately, T-SQL allows implicit conversion from integers to `DATETIME`, making this very easy to miss). And if you put that in an `EXEC`, don't forget you need to escape the quotes by doubling them.

Comment: I would be surprised if that doesn't return any rows, as you want data that is between 11 June 1905  and 06 January 2030; that's a big ol' time frame.

Comment: That solved my issue - I was missing basic syntax: the statement works when set as: "exec('...WHERE curDate >= DATEADD(WEEK, 0, ''2021-04-30'') 
  AND curDate  < DATEADD(WEEK, 6500, ''2021-04-30'')...')"

Comment: For future reference, it is often (usually?) impossible to debug fragments of code to identify the source of an execution error. You were lucky this time. Bu let's not depend on luck - post the complete statement (or better - a repro) that demonstrates the problem. TBH your where clause logic makes little sense. Adding 6000 weeks to any date will return a date that is **FAR** beyond that starting point.  Adding 0 (zero) weeks to any date is just nonsense - that will return the original date